# Joining child lists of 2 lists conditionally

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of objects, each containing a list of child objects and an ID to join on, in the below structure.

```
[
 {
    ItemId:1,
    JoinId: null,
    ChildList: { parent items }
 }
]
```

One of the lists purely contains items without a JoinId, and the other contains items that are either also in the first with a different child list, and a "JoinId" to link it back to the first.  This join Id is purely used to connect the 2 lists.

My issue is how I can join these lists to return all of the unique items from either of the 2 lists, with their child lists joined together based on the "JoinId" property.  Is anyone able to shed some light on it?

An example of the input/output is:

Input:

```
List1
[
 {
    ItemId:1,
    JoinId: null,
    ChildList: [{ Item1 items }]
 },
 {
    ItemId:2,
    JoinId: null,
    ChildList: [{ Item2 items }]
 }
]

List2
[
 {
    ItemId:3,
    JoinId: 1,
    ChildList: [{ Item1 items }]
 },
 {
    ItemId:2,
    JoinId: 1,
    ChildList: [{ Item1 items }]
 }
]
```

Output

```
[
 {
    ItemId:1,
    JoinId: null,
    ChildList: [{ Item1 items }]
 },
 {
    ItemId:2,
    JoinId: null,
    ChildList: [
                { Item2 items }, 
                { Item1 items }
               ]
 },    
 {
    ItemId:3,
    JoinId: 1,
    ChildList: [{ Item1 items }]
 }
]
```

Comment: What is the other part of the "either" for the second list? Can you provide some C# data types/classes instead of pseudo-code? How can `List2`:`ItemId:3` have a `JoinId` of `1` and also have `ItemId:2` with `JoinId:1`?

Comment: This dataset is a monster to deal with.  It's doable, but it warrants asking the question: Is this what the data you were given looks like, or did you transform the data into this structure?  If the source data is in another form, it might be helpful to show that form.  Also, have you considered use of Data Tables?  this might be complex enough to warrant filling the data into Data Tables to make transforms easier.

Comment: This is complex enough that some people might consider it more of an algorithm query question than a LINQ-specific question.

Comment: @NetMage, My bad, it's either contained in the 1st list based on the key, or solely in the 2nd List.  As for the Items, item 2 and 3 have taken their child items from Item 1 (edited the child ltem's to show which they've come from), as for the C# classes, the stripped down version here would be 2 integers, and an array of an object type.  I can give you a more formal version with getters and setters if you need.

Comment: @JamesHoux I'd agree it's a bit annoying, the data was initially in a Parent-Child-Grandchild structure, and this was the best attempt I had at hopefully simplifying the question.  In this example the list would have Item1, and then on Item1's {child item}'s we'd have a {grandchild items} that would contain the id for Item2 and Item3.  Item2 would also be in the main list as a stand alone. (Hopefully that makes sense).

Overall I need to combine the child arrays based on their parent OR grandchild items with the correct version, giving a list that looks like the output

Comment: It sounds like data is better represented as a tree. If yes, I'd stick it in a tree and write an algorithm to recurse the tree to transform the data into the output I wanted.

Comment: So `List1:ItemId1`, `List2:ItemId2` and `List2:ItemId3` all have the same `ChildList`? What does the `JoinId` mean/represent? What is "the key" - you haven't mentioned that before? Can you edit your question instead of adding in comments?